# Sending webservice email from mssql

Tags: sql-server

Just want to ask can microsoft SQL server 2012 send webservice email ?  Currently my client using an email provider and dont have SMTP server.Thanks

Comment: You will have to write custom code to use their webmail provider.  Ruby with mechanize may work.

Comment: It's possible to use [database mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189635(v=sql.110).aspx), but depending on the setup you may need to work with the client or the client's email provider to allow your system to send email with the correct domain name.

Comment: Hi, Is there any sample i can reference to ? thanks